# In Mountain, which keys on a keyboard correspond to pitch-wise notes?

Tags: mountain

In Mountain, I've played most of the melodies to my mountain and have wanted to create my own melodies from songs I have played off-game. Which keys on the keyboard correspond to which notes(in the key of C major)